# Pyspark refer to table created using sql

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

When I create a table using SQL in Spark, for example:

```
sql('CREATE TABLE example SELECT a, b FROM c')
```

How can I pull that table into the python namespace (I can't think of a better term) so that I can update it? Let's say I want to replace `NaN` values in the table like so:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
table = sql('SELECT * FROM example')
for column in columns:
    table = table.withColumn(column,F.when(F.isnan(F.col(column)),F.col(column)).otherwise(None))
```

Does this operation update the original `example` table created with SQL? If I were to run `sql('SELECT * FROM example')show()` would I see the updated results? When the original `CREATE TABLE example ...` SQL runs, is `example` automatically added to the python namespace?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `sql` function returns a new `DataFrame`, so the table is not modified. If you want to write a `DataFrame`'s contents into a table created in spark, do it like this:

```
table.write.mode("append").saveAsTable("example")
```

But what you are doing is actually changing the schema of a table, in that case

```
table.createOrReplaceTempView("mytempTable") 
sql("create table example2 as select * from mytempTable");
```